# Why does the Quran speak about the truth of the Torah?

Tags: quran, tafseer

> Then, you are those [same ones who are] killing one another and
> evicting a party of your people from their homes, cooperating against
> them in sin and aggression. And if they come to you as captives, you
> ransom them, although their eviction was forbidden to you. **So do you
> believe in part of the Scripture and disbelieve in part?** Then what is
> the recompense for those who do that among you except disgrace in
> worldly life; and on the Day of Resurrection they will be sent back to
> the severest of punishment. And Allah is not unaware of what you do.
> ([2] Al-Baqarah : 85)

Which Torah is the Koran talking about?

Comment: I can't follow your logic regarding the verse shared it actually shows that although knowing the Torah (or its truth) Jews are not following it. In other words they seem to believe in parts of it and disbelieve in other since they are not acing upon it.

Answer (score 1):

If you go through verses above it in Sura Bakarah (chapter 2), you can see Quran is going through the history of Bani Israel (children of Israel), about the favors they received, the trials they have gone through and how Allah delivered them from these etc. So this verse you are talking about is not discussing the textual accuracy of Torah but about the children of Israel who selectively followed their book while discarding the portions they disliked. They didn't follow part of Torah, not because they believed it is not original text but they disliked what is said, in this verse it is said "though expelling them was unlawful for you."

There is lesson for Muslims in this, that is Muslims can be careful not to selectively follow Quran, instead of following the whole Quran.

Comment: So this event did not happen in the time of the Prophet?

Comment: Quran is going through the history of children of Israel. you can read the verses above and below it to know this.